# Improper Integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Does the following limit exist ? Justify.

$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{N}^{e^N}x(e^{-x^{2016}})dx$.

If yes, then what is the limit? I am asking for some **hints**, not for the full solution. I mean what is the general strategy for solving this type of improper integral.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hint: you probably know that if an infinite sum converges then the tail goes to zero. If $\int^\infty_0 f(x) dx$ converges, what can you say about the tail $\int^\infty_N f(x) dx$ as $N \to \infty$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cauchy Criterion?

Comment: The 'general strategy' first step is $t = x^{2016}$.

Comment: Hint: use the substitution u = x^2 to get rid of the x in the integral